# extract numbers from string in ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string as

> Teen Mom 2 (Season 5) | Ep. 7 | These Are The Days | MTV

I need to extract only Season number and Episode number from this. ie. 5 and 7.

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

Use `string.scan` function like below.

```
> "Teen Mom 2 (Season 5) | Ep. 7 | These Are The Days | MTV".scan(/(?<=Season )\d+|(?<=Ep\. )\d+/)
=> ["5", "7"]
```

- `(?<=Season )` Positive look-behind asserts that the match must be preceded by `Season` string.
- `\d+` Match one or more digits.

Comment: or `(?:Season|Ep\.)\s+\K\d+`

Comment: Good answer, great \Komment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method which generates a named match:

```
txt = "Teen Mom 2 (Season 5) | Ep. 7 | These Are The Days | MTV"
match = /Season (?<season>\d+).*Ep\. (?<ep>\d+)/.match txt

match['season']
# => 5
match['ep']
# => 7
```